# Problem with importing key to blockchain.info

Tags: private-key, private-key-export

Problem

1. downloaded my wallet into a drive which does not have enough disk space left.
2. has not currently synced yet
3. transferred bitcoins by mistake whilst it was syncing
4. I have backed up my wallet but have not encrypted it yet.
5. I'm trying to gain access to my coins via importing of keys to .blockchain website.
6. I followed [this guide](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7536/how-do-i-export-my-private-keys-from-my-bitcoin-qt-client):

> To export a private key from your Satoshi bitcoin-qt client:
>
> ```
> launch your bitcoin client as usual and wait for it to load the blockchain and start up
> click on 'help' in the menu bar (top right)
> click on 'debug window'
> select the 'console' tab
> type: walletpassphrase "your walletpassphrase here" 600
> type: dumpprivkey [your public key here]
> this will return the private key, you can copy it now; ensure you clear your clipboard/history afterwards
> type: walletlock    }
> ```

All it says in the console..

```
safemode,warning what is not displayed may be incorrect
might need to download upgrade, and nodes   code-2
```

I want to access my coins via blockchain website. My operating system is Windows; the client is bitcoin-qt version 0.8.1.

How do I export these keys?