# Export Private Keys from Bitcoin-QT

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, private-key

I am still attempting to complete the receipt of a payment in BitCoin-QT. The initial synchronization is beginning to be a hassle so I thought I might get my key and transfer my wallet to Blockchain.info.

I followed the directions in [How do I export my private keys from my Bitcoin-QT?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7536/how-do-i-export-my-private-keys-from-my-bitcoin-qt-client)
to get my private key. All I get back for `dumpprivkey[]` is:

> Invalid Bitcoin address (code -5).

I thought maybe I had the wrong address so I entered `listreceivedbyaddress 0 true`.

There are only a couple of addresses since I have a new wallet. All of the addresses returned the same "Invalid Bitcoin address" message. What is going on? I know one of these addresses was used to give to an exchange for my new BC. Is it simply because my blockchain is incomplete and the transaction is incomplete?

Comment: Are you unlocking your wallet before you attempt to use 'dumpprivkey'?

Comment: Yes. I unlocked it.

Comment: Do the addresses you are trying to dump start with a "1"? Not being synchronised will not stop you from doing these actions.

Comment: No. I made the mistake of literally applying the instructions from How do I export private keys.... I was using the [ ] when entering the call dumpprivkey. I took those out and everything is fine. Thx.

Comment: You can post your own answer to this question stating your solution, and click the check mark to accept it. Otherwise, the site will continue to show the question as "unanswered".

Answer (score 4):

My solution to the question for an encrypted wallet:

walletpassphrase "......." 600
dumpprivkey ......

I made the mistake of including the brackets [ ] when entering the public key after the call dumpprivkey.