# Bitcoin address with money need help getting it?

Tags: address, payment

I have money in a bitcoin address how do I get the money out of it? I am new to bitcoin any help is helpful.

Comment: Are you asking how to sell bitcoins for national currency or are you asking how to perform a Bitcoin transaction?

Comment: Transaction, I got a payment for someone and I gave them by bitcoin address but when i checked my wallet it says there is no money in there. So I checked the address and it has the money in it but is not linked to my wallet. So I guess the question is how do I get the money out of the address? If that makes sense.

Comment: Are you using Bitcoin Core and it is still synchronizing? (Says "Synchronizing with the network…" at the bottom?)

Comment: Yes, It was fully synchronized but today it gave me an error and it now says reindexing blocks on disk. I think there was a bad block or something.

Answer (score 0):

If Bitcoin hasn't synchronized ? export the private key to other wallet and spend the funds on private keys' addresses.

Follow steps here to get your private keys
[How do I export my private keys from my Bitcoin-Qt client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7536/how-do-i-export-my-private-keys-from-my-bitcoin-qt-client)